# Mongos Stale Config Error

Tags: java, mongodb, sharding

Getting the following errors in my mongos log upon attempting to query a sharded collection.

```
ns: database.coll could not initialize cursor across all shards because : 
stale config detected for ns: database.coll ParallelCursor::_init @ 
rs_a/hostA:27018,hostB:27018 attempt: 0
```

The error is originating from an application server running mongos which loads its config from three distributed config servers. The mongo cluster itself has two shards each with a three member replica set. The error is accompanied by severely degraded performance.

Running Mongo 2.0.1 and using the java driver.

Comment: Are you seeing the error from only 1 mongos?

Comment: I had been seeing this on several (all) of my mongos processes running on individual app servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair deal of troubleshooting the final solution to this problem was to restart all of my config servers. Unfortunately flushRouterConfig would attempt to reconnect but return the same stale config error message.

Note that since sharding configuration servers are not a replicaset, when one server is down they become read only and will not accept any chunk change information.

I wish I had a little more insight into this problem. It seems almost certainly to be a bug in mongos or in the config server for 2.0.1 as my replica sets/shards underwent no topology change.

Comment: so what you are saying is that the query was always failing before you restarted the configuration server, then after restart it is now totally fixed? If so could you open a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org with as much details as you can? thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, I should have time in the next few days. I'll update this post with the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing the error from only 1 mongos?
And on that mongos, are you seeing errors to all replica sets or just one?

Based on those answers you can narrow down the issue.
If you feel like only a few processes are having errors, try restarting them or issue a db.adminCommand("flushRouterConfig")